# Django: How to pass a javascript var to Django URL as parameter in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

How can I pass a javascript variable to a Django URL? It presents a,

> TypeError at /object/Query/details
>
> view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'

I am trying to redirect to another HTML page following this process:

HTML Search Input > Pass to Javascript through input button `onclick` > Pass to JQuery Ajax `sendQueryData`> Redirect to another page using Django `render()`
;considering I had to do more things on the passed parameters to the URL upon passing them in AJAX.

The main problem lies on this two lines (I think):

```
url_page = url + "{% url 'view' 'query'%}"; //supposedly how we get parameters (but query is a javascript `var`
```

and

```
url =url.replace('query' , query); //where I intend to correctly build the url forcing the query to take its place in the url
```

I'm just not quite sure if my `urls.py`, ajax call on javascript in Django url are all aligned at all.

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='homepage'),

#--- Home ---
url(r'^search/pass/$', views.pass_query, name='pass_query'),

# View Object Details
url(r'^object/(?P<query>\w+)/details', views.view(), name='view')
```

My HTML

```
<div id="button-group" class="button-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" onclick="redirect_to_url(0)" value="View Inventory"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-space col-sm-3" onclick="redirect_to_url(1)" value= "View Details"/>
```

Javascript

```
function redirect_to_url(to_page){
    var query = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var url = document.URL;
    url = url.slice(0, -1);

    if (to_page === 0) {
         url_page = url + "{% url 'view' 'query'%}";
         sendQueryData(url_page, query);
    }
    else if(to_page === 1) {
        url_page = url + "{% url 'another_view' 'query' %}";
        sendQueryData(url_page, query);

    }
    return false;
}

function sendQueryData(url, query){
    url =url.replace('query' , query);

    if (query === ""){
        alert("Input Required");
    }else{

        $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
          },
          type: "POST",
          url: "/search/pass/",
          data: {
              'query' : query,
              'url' : url
          },
          success: function(result){
             alert(result);
             window.location.href = url;
          }
        });
    }

}
```

Views.py

```
def pass_query(request):
query =request.POST['query']
  print(query) 
  return HttpResponse(query)

def view(request):
  return render(request, 'plexus/view.html')
```

> Edit:
>
> The error occurs at AJAX Success function. If I debugged it correctly,
>   I tried to change the url in `window.location.href =` to another
>   static URL that doesn't have a parameter unlike
>   `url(r'^object/(?P<query>\w+)/details', views.view, name='view'),` and
>   it does work well. If this is so, maybe I can re-title this on how to
>   add a parameter to the url where Django URL is looking for an
>   argument.

Comment: Can we please see the code for `views.view`?

Comment: @pocketkings oh yes I edited. Also I found that the error occurs on `render()` I'm going to re-do the question a bit, since it since that I'm having a problem how to add a parameter on template load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `query` parameter to the `views.view` definition:

```
def view(request, query):
```

If it is possible to call `view` without providing a query then you could define it as:

```
def view(request, query=None):
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! I thought my problem was because I cannot add a parameter in Django urls like how its shown in tutorials because its a javascript variable. Saved me a lot of time! Thanks again!